# JDBC как начать работать

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Только начал изучать Java. Дошел до JDBC. Но многого не понимаю. Какую IDE использовать? Как должно осуществляться взаимодействие с MySQL? Как вообще сервер запустить?
.

Comment: Сколько стоят две секунды кирпичей если козырь буби?

Comment: сначала напишите hello world, в интернете найдёте миллион туториалов

Comment: Вопрос задан про JDBC и тут же - какую IDE использовать... причем здесь вообще IDE... На Вашем уровне лучшая IDE это консоль, поверьте. Начните с неё, хоть поймёте что происходит....

Comment: @Inwar2006 Не надо консоль. Я вот например начал с ide turbo-pascacalь, И теперь без IDE вообще не могу. Но JDBC при этом знаю более-менее (в сторону более:). Для жабы могу посоветовать Netbeans. Но в освоении именно JDBC это действительно как в коменте про бибу и кирпичи.

Comment: Ключевая фраза "без IDE вообще не могу". Удачи.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на Ваши вопросы без постановки граничных условий требует отдельного написания нескольких книг. :) Хотя я Вас понимаю, когда-то сам искал хоть какую-то вменяемую зацепку - "с чего начать копать". Главное - **начните таки копать**, а не оставайтесь на уровне "спрошу-ка я на стеке или хабре, самому копнуть влом".

JDBC, работа с базами - [глава 5](http://mirknig.su/knigi/programming/192860-java-biblioteka-professionala-v-2-h-tomah-2016.html). Хотя том 1 я тоже рекомендую прочитать и детально проработать, настраивает на нужный ход мыслей. В свое время именно он мне "почерк поставил", да еще, пожалуй, Роберт Мартин с его "Чистым кодом". Помогает независимо от текущего используемого языка, даже в работе с PHP. Кстати, в 1 томе найдете ответ на свой вопрос "Какую IDE использовать?"

[Как установить MySQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20mysql) - выбираете свою ОС, читаете, пробуете.

P.S. Селяви программиста всегда на 99% самообучение. А для этого в первую очередь нужно научиться учиться. И экспериментировать на практике. Удачи!

Comment: Ещё напишите где искать драйвер JDBC для mysql. Или connecto. Как там он у них называется? Часто прячут драйвера эти, что днем с огнем не сыщешь.

Answer (score 0):

Сервер MySQL нужно установить если нет?
Подойдет любая IDE: NetBeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA.

Как должно осуществляться взаимодействие с MySQL? - качаешь jar'ник JDBC и по гайдам, обучалкам и/или видео-урокам следуешь шаг за шагом.

Как вообще сервер запустить? - он запускается при старте ОС если она не отключена в службах ОС.